# Doctrine 2 Filters - Wrap response from SQLFilter->getParameter() in %s

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on using Doctrine Filters to apply filters based on query string values provided during my API's collection GET requests, for example;

`/foo?filters[title]=my+search+term`

I enable the title filter based on the presence of the key in `filters[]`, setting the parameter to equal the query value;

```
// Repository Class (within a loop, enabling filters dynamically)
$this
    ->getEntityManager()
    ->getFilters()
    ->enable($filterName)
    ->setParameter($key, $value);
```

This enables the filter, which runs as expected, and sets the parameter. The title filter method is as follows;

```
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        if (!$this->hasParameter('title')) {
            return '';
        }

        return sprintf(
            '%s.title LIKE %s',
            $targetTableAlias,
            $this->getParameter('title')
        );
    }
```

The problem I'm aiming to solve is the wrapping of the parameter returned by `$this->getParameter()` in `%`s for the `LIKE` clause. The returned parameter is run through `PDO::quote()` so string concatenation won't work here (as this results in `%'my search term'%` instead of `'%my search term%'`).

Is there a way to achieve this without wrapping the string in `%`s when calling `setParameter()`? I'd rather have the filter responsible for that than have to store additional configuration against the filter config indicating that I should wrap the parameter myself when setting it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What about to remove quotes manually?  For example sprintf("%s.title LIKE '%%%s%%'", $targetTableAlias, stripslashes(substr($this->getParameter('title'), 1, -1)));

Comment: @ArtemZhuravlev I considered this but I guess I expected Doctrine to provide the ability to do this, as you're then manipulating an escaped string. I think the best solution is going to be to handle providing the `%`s when setting the parameter.